# How to find out all the cursors associated with a connection in python-Snowflake connector

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

Is there any function in python-snowflake connector API to get the list of all cursors that were derived using the connection object. Also can you please confirm if exiting a function call will close the cursors?

```
def function(self,qry):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    return cur.execute(qry)

def proc(self):
    sel_cur = self.function("select.....")
    ....
    ....
    ....
    upd_cur = self.function("update.....")
    ....
    sel_cur1 = self.function("select.....")
    ....
    del_cur = self.function("delete.....")
    sel_cur2 = self.function("select.....")
```

The above two functions are written inside a class. There are multiple cursors getting created in proc(). Once the proc() exits, will it close the cursors? I assume they are not yet closed, but they become inaccessible due to local scope. I think they are still occupying the memory. Please clarify. I want to find out if any cursors are still open for a given connection. Please help me how to achieve this in python-snowflake connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be a list of cursors for a connection. Exiting a function call will not close a cursor (it is possible to create a cursor in a function call, return it to the caller, and verify that the cursor is still open).

[Context managers and the with statement](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/) are an easy way to ensure a cursor and a connection are closed when no longer required.

```
with snowflake.connector.connect(**connection_parameters) as connection:

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:

        sql = "select * from product"

        # Simple fetch and print
        cursor.execute(sql)
        for (productId, name, parentId) in cursor:
        # ...
```

When exiting the *with cursor* block, the cursor will be closed. Similarly when exiting the *with connection* block, the connection will be closed.

Comment: Does a Python ContextManager automatically call .close() on Snowflake objects, and how is it possible to know either way?  It seems safe to assume so in this case, but I am interested to know how we can tell that the ContextManager has successfully cleaned up resources.

Comment: To take advantage of Context Managers, a class should implement .__enter__() and .__exit__(). The Snowflake connector does have both, and .__exit__() calls .close.() https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/blob/9b586d4c37f5206742f418ae1d66fc83248cacbe/src/snowflake/connector/connection.py#L1545

Comment: I did not realise the connector was open source. Thanks for clarifying, very helpful.